# Form authentication without cookies

Tags: asp.net, authentication, cookies

Is it possible that form authentication can work in asp.net without cookies? I have learnt some where that without cookies authentication work normally but with help of token in query string but when I am disabling cookies my form authentication is failing with message in browser similar as shown in 
[Figure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D92AD.png)

Do I need to make some configuration changes to make it work with help of query string token?

Comment: Why do you want to do it without cookies?

Comment: @mason there is requirement where i need to design a solution implementing form authentication without cookies due to security purpose.

Comment: That makes it less secure!